# PHP URL Encoding (FileMaker IWP)

Tags: php, wordpress, filemaker

I have hosted a FileMaker database on the web using FileMaker Instant Web Publishing. I am trying to access it directly - as in bypass the login page - using the php command header().

This is the code I am currently using.

```
header("location: http://<serverIPaddress>/fmi/iwp/cgi?dbpath=%2Ffmi%2Fiwp%2Fcgi%3F-db%3D<databasename>%26-startsession&amp;acct=account&amp;name=<username>&amp;password=<password>&amp;login=Login&amp;-authdb");
```

I got this code from here: http://lnx.acidsoft.net/problemsolved/bypass-filemaker-iwp-login-via-url.html

I don't believe the FileMaker part is as relevant, since accessing the database works fine when I remove all the other encoding stuff, I just can't bypass the login that way.
I believe it might be more of a problem with how the URL is structured and me not having enough experience to know how certain browsers or what language I'm using will affect the URL.

When I currently try to execute it, I get two dialog boxes.

First, I get one that says:

> Bad Request
>
> The server could not process your request due to a missing command: "”.

The second one says:

> Bad Request
>
> The server could not process your request because your session has timed out, been closed, or communication with the server has been lost.
>
> Please reselect the database to begin a new session.
> If you cannot open the database, please contact your database administrator.

Any ideas? I am using a button to call the .php file that calls this particular line, and I'm testing it on Safari and Google Chrome.

Comment: What is currently happening when you execute the php script? Obviously you have switched out <serverIPAddress> with your real ip address?

Comment: Yes sir I have switched out the <serverIPaddress> with the real IP address. (Also the username, pass, database, etc.)  When I currently try to execute it, I get two dialog boxes. 

First, I get one that says: 
Bad Request 
The server could not process your request due to a missing command: "”.

The second one says: 
Bad Request 
The server could not process your request because your session has timed out, been closed, or communication with the server has been lost.

Please reselect the database to begin a new session.
If you cannot open the database, please contact your database administrator.

Comment: I assume it has to do with the server verifying the session. If you log into the page you are trying to bypass can you see if any session variables are set (hopefully a decipherable cookie)?

Comment: If you do not need security on this file, couldn't you just remove the need for authentication? If you still need it, you could always use a dedicated file to auto-login and then open the target file.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, I had same exact problem.  Found an example of a working link here:
https://community.filemaker.com/thread/73562?start=0&tstart=0

...and the difference with my (failed) URL was the = in the url should be encoded to %3D
For me, having the actual = symbol made the link not work.

```
http://<DATABASE IP OR HOSTNAME>/fmi/iwp/cgi?dbpath=%2Ffmi%2Fiwp%2Fcgi%3F-db%3D<DATABASE NAME>%26-startsession&acct=account&name=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&login=Login&-authdb
```

Good luck!